# aggregate in j column to string column name, data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to create a summarized data.table using the j column, but assign to a name stored in a variable.

For example, I can do this:

```
x = data.table(c(1,2,3,4,5,6),c(2,2,2,3,3,3))

x[,.("a" = mean(V1), "b" = max(V1)),by=V2]
```

which returns as wanted

```
   V2 a b
1:  2 2 3
2:  3 5 6
```

Now instead of using the name "a", I would like to use a variable name:

```
varname = "a"

x[,.(varname = mean(V1), "b" = max(V1)), by=V2]
```

I'd like it to return the same output, but of course here column a is labeled as "varname". I've tried using eval, get, and others and haven't figured out the right syntax. Is this built in, or will I have to relabel the name outside of data.table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `setnames` after the aggregation

```
out <- x[,.( mean(V1), "b" = max(V1)), by=V2]
setnames(out, 'V1', varname)
out
#   V2 a b
#1:  2 2 3
#2:  3 5 6
```

---

Or use `setNames`

```
x[, setNames(.(mean(V1), max(V1)), c(varname, "b")), by = V2]
```

---

With `tidyverse`, the `lhs` evaluation is possible

```
library(tidyverse)
x %>%
   group_by(V2) %>% 
   summarise(!! varname := mean(V1))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#     V2     a
#   <dbl> <dbl>
#1     2     2
#2     3     5
```

Comment: Is there a reason the eval or get syntax doesn't work on the left hand side?

Comment: @AllenWang  It is difficult to get that to work, but in tidyverse you can do `x %>% group_by(V2) %>% summarise(!! varname := mean(V1))`

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can put the functions into a named list as follows:

```
x[, lapply(structure(list(mean, max), names=c(varname, "b")), 
        function(f) f(V1)), 
    by=V2]
```